# Tomcat: Qual é o critério para que a coluna "Thread" apareça na página "Connectors" do Probe?

Tags: java, tomcat

Olá, eu gostaria de saber o que deve ser feito para que a coluna "Thread" apareça na tela "Connectors" do probe, essa coluna aparece normalmente na minha instalação do Tomcat 6.0 + Probe 2.3.3, mas ao usar as mesmas configurações em outra máquina com Tomcat 6.0 + Probe 2.3.3, essa coluna não aparece.

EDIT: A maquina que funciona, roda Windows com java 1.6.0_18-b07. A máquina que não funciona, roda Linux com java 1.6.0_18-b07.

[image: Minha máquina]

[image: Outra máquina]

Qualquer ajuda será apreciada, desde já, obrigado.